# How to select value from selectlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How to select a text from `selectlist`? I want to auto select name "Dave" name from back-end on line `First_Name_SELECT = "Dave";`

```
<select asp-for="Person.First_Name" asp-items="@Model.First_Name_SELECT">
</select>

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string? First_Name { get; set; }
    public SelectList? First_Name_SELECT { get; set; }
    
    First_Name_SELECT = new SelectList(await _services.Get_Names());
    First_Name_SELECT = "Dave";
 

 public async Task<List<string>> Get_Names()
 {
        IQueryable<string> Query = (from m in _context2.Names_DbSet
                                    select m.First_Names).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m);
        return await Query.ToListAsync();
 }
```

** ****UPDATE**** ** Following code works fine below but why First_Name_SELECT doesn't work? is this becuase I am using IQueryable?

```
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string? Last_Name { get; set; }
    public SelectList? Last_Name_SELECT { get; set; }

Last_Name_SELECT = new SelectList(await _services.Get_LastNames());
var testing = Last_Name_SELECT .Where(x => x.Value.Contains("Name8")).FirstOrDefault();
        testing.Selected = true;


public List<SelectListItem> Get_LastNames()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> Query = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Selected =true, Value = "name1", Text = "name1" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "name2", Text = "name2" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "name3", Text = "name3" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "name4", Text = "name4" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "name5", Text = "name5" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "name6", Text = "name6" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "name7", Text = "name7" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "name8", Text = "name8" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "name9", Text = "name9" }
        };

        return Query;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried First_Name = "Dave";

Comment: just tried it. didnt seem to be working

Comment: See binding Person.First_Name. It should be valid property in your model.  I think you should change to @Model.First_Name instead of Person.First_Name.

Comment: Do you have a Person model?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model Person, you can try the below code:

```
 var First_Name_SELECTSelectedValue = "Dave";
 First_Name_SELECT = new SelectList(await _services.Get_Names(), First_Name_SELECTSelectedValue);
```

result:
[image]
You can read [SelectList(IEnumerable, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-selectlist-ctor(system-collections-ienumerable-system-object)) to know more.

> public SelectList (System.Collections.IEnumerable items, object
> selectedValue);

Comment: Hi @dave , I test your Last_Name_SELECT, but I meet the null error at `var testing = Last_Name_SELECT .Where(x => x.Value.Contains("Name8")).FirstOrDefault();`  . But your First_Name_SELECT selected set  is different with Last_Name_SELECT, if you wonder whether is the reason of  using IQueryable, you can use the same code about setting selected to set First_Name_SELECT to see the result.